# \small wrapped around table doesn't work

Tags: tables, floats, fontsize

Nothing happens, even though I've applied `\small` around the table.  No observable change in font size.  Howcome?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
{\small
        \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
            \toprule
            Experiment  &   Enzyme              &   Substrate   &       Enzyme inhibitor\\
            \midrule
            A           &   Trypsin             &   Casein      &       Trypsin inhibitor\\
            B           &   Chymotrypsin        &   Casein      &       Trypsin inhibitor\\
            C           &   Chymotrypsinogen    &   Casein      &       Trypsin inihibitor\\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Formatting macros around floats (`table` and `figure`) don't affect them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong position of `\small`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

        \begin{table}[!htb]
            \centering\small
            \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
            \toprule
            Experiment  &   Enzyme              &   Substrate   &       Enzyme inhibitor\\
            \midrule
            A           &   Trypsin             &   Casein      &       Trypsin inhibitor\\
            B           &   Chymotrypsin        &   Casein      &       Trypsin inhibitor\\
            C           &   Chymotrypsinogen    &   Casein      &       Trypsin inihibitor\\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

\end{document
```

Comment: Ah, I see - your way works.  I did try a lot of variations including one analogous to that one you have shown me, but they didn't work because I was under impression you had to close the affected text inside parentheses.  My way was giving errors like - `! Misplaced \crcr.
\endtabular ->\crcr 
                    \egroup \egroup $\egroup 
l.22   \end{tabular}
                    
?`

Comment: @ptrcao: my guess is that this particular problem came from putting a brace between `\\` and `\bottomrule`. That doesn't work: `\bottomrule` (and similar commands) must come just after `\\`.